# Wait until a tap gesture from user?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my spritekit game I would like users to choose starting positions on a map by tapping and then adding the sprite to the appropriate place. I am struggling to figure out how to make the game "wait" for the user input without advancing.

My initial thought was an infinite while loop, but that seems to simply freeze the game.

```
    if self.settingsInstance.startPositionMode == "custom" {
        for player in self.settingsInstance.gamePlayers {
            if player.isPlayerHuman == true {
                //Allow human to choose
                player.isCurrentlyActive = true
                while player.hasStartAssigned == false {
          ~ -> Wait until a tap gesture occurs 
                }
                print("success!")
                if player.hasStartAssigned == true{
                    player.isCurrentlyActive = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In my tap handling function I first check for `player.isCurrentlyActive == true` and then set the `.hasStartAssigned` to true, but so far this method isnt working.

Does anyone have some pointers for how to "wait" for user input?

Thanks!

Comment: you should learn about async code and delegates. no infinite loop etc are needed

Comment: just start the game and hold on while you receive taps - then set the start location and and check if start location is set

Comment: To clarify muescha (I think he ment this) . Start your game "on hold waiting for user-touch", and fire the "continue game" method when you receive the user touch. Do not run any infinite loops.

Comment: How would Async code help? I also don't really see what delegates would do in this case?

Comment: Do you still need help with this? The answer is already above, only set up the game before the user touches the screen, and once he does then call a separate function that will actually start the game

Comment: You need to read about and understand the sprite kit game loop. whilst waiting for a tap, SK is still doing physics calculations, the update() method is being called etc, so you just need to make sure you don't do anything in update or start anything moving until you have received & processed those taps.

Comment: Where in your code did you have you loop?

Comment: Thanks Steve, I guess I don't have much of an understanding of that game loop. I had been operating under that fact that gestures acted like interrupt  routines, but it seems that it isn't quite the case. I guess I'll read up on this stuff. I've fixed the issue by moving the start of the game to a condition in the tap recognizer. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Yeah doing that while is a wrong way to go. That runs on a main thread and *freezes it* in your case. Just implement touches began or implement recognizers correctly. There are a lot of answers here about that. If you are still stuck, let us know, and somebody will eventially wrote an example for you.

Comment: Thanks WhirlWind, I I think I've got it now. I completely miss-understood how  sprite kit worked. I now know to use the update method in my scene to check the status of various parameters and update as needed.